# open UITableViewController as an item of UItabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ipod

I created an UITabbarController that its first item is an UIViewController, this UIViewController contains a button that must open UITableViewController.

I created the UITableViewController and UIViewController in the StoryBoard and gave them identifier name.

my problem is,when I press the button that is in the UIViewController to open the table,  it opens the UITableViewController but without the tabBar and I want the UITableViewController be as an item from the tabBar (item opens other item)

how to do this ?? can anyone show me sample code
sorry for my bad explanation.

consider that I'm using Xcode4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embed ur view controller inside a navigation controller. make this navigation controller as the tabBar Controller's view controller(first item) .Don't present the table view controller modally . instead segue it using navigation controller.

Comment: Sorry I'm new in iphone, so I can't understand this steps. could you illustrate this please

Comment: I think that this is not what I need, I need the viewController and the tableViewController both are in the root tabbar in the same item but when I press the button that in viewController opens the tableViewController

Comment: ok, if I want the button action opens the tableView programmatically, I wont drag from button to the table. So, what the code will be?

Comment: UIStoryboard*storyboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"];
    TableViewController*tableViewController=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"(yourIdentifier)"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController :tableViewController animated:YES];

Comment: another question here please, If I want to open this UITableviewController from other class and want it to seem in the tabbar but want to skip to view the ViewController first, how can I do this? hope that you got my mean.