# Skip ViewController and opens UITableViewController in UITabbar

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

I was asked before for a solution and I got it as shown in the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446001/open-uitableviewcontroller-as-an-item-of-uitabbarcontroller/12446140#comment16736006_12446140)

Now, my question is:

If I want to open this UITableviewController from other class directly and want it to seem in the tabbar but want to skip to view the ViewController first, how can I do this? hope that anyone got my mean.

Comment: You have a tabbar with navigation controller and in the navigation root controller you have the table view, right? Do you want to switch from another tab to the table view or you want to switch from same tab but another view in navigation controller?

Comment: I want to open the table view from the tabbar but skip the viewController

Answer (score 0):

for this you will just have to add tableViewController as the childViewController by replacing the one did for view controller as mentioned above...